# Blink Adafruit_NeoPixel

Tags: programming, neopixel

I wish to blink all the strip. In the code below it just blink the first LED, how can I fix it?

Code:

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>


#define PIN 6
#define NUM_LEDS 24


Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUM_LEDS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);


void setup() {
  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
}

void loop() {
  strip.setPixelColor(0, 255, 255, 255);
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);
  strip.setPixelColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument of `setPixelColor` is is the number of the led. In your case 0, so the first led.

Instead use a `for` loop to set all the leds from 0 until (excluding) 24 (which is stored in `NUM_LEDS`).

```
void loop()
{
  for (int led = 0; led < NUM_LEDS ; led++)
  {
    strip.setPixelColor(led, 255, 255, 255);
  }
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);

  for (int led = 0; led < NUM_LEDS ; led++)
  {
    strip.setPixelColor(led, 255, 255, 255);
  }
  strip.show();
  delay(1000);
```

To make the code better (shorter, but more important more maintainable, and reducing code duplication), create a separate function:

```
void loop() 
{
  setLeds(255);
  setLeds(0);
}

void setLeds(int intensity)
{
  for (int led = 0; led < NUM_LEDS ; led++)
  {
    strip.setPixelColor(led, intensity, intensity, intensity);
  }

  strip.show();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. In the longer script I presume it should be strip.setPixelColor(led, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: Yes, because the argument `intensity` decides when values 0 or 255 are used.